# how can a find a patter of numbers in consecutive lines with python?

Tags: python, numbers, line-by-line, specification-pattern

Im learning python but i have some problems with my scripts yet.

I have a file similar to:

```
1 5
2 5
3 5
4 2
5 1
6 7
7 7
8 8
```

I want to print the pairs of numbers 2-1 in consecutive lines, just taking the column 2 to find them, and then, print the column 1 and 2 with the results. The result will be similar to this:

```
4 2 
5 1
```

I'm trying to do it with python, because my file has 4,000,000 data. So, this is my script:

```
import linecache

final_lines = []
with open("file.dat") as f:
for i, line in enumerate(f, 1):
    if "1" in line:
        if "2" in linecache.getline("file.dat", i-1):
            linestart = i - 1 
            final_lines.append(linecache.getline("file.dat", linestart))
print(final_lines)
```

and the result is:

```
['2\n', '2\n', '2\n']
```

What I must to change in my script to fit the result that I want?, Can you guide me please? Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you need to use `linecache`? opening a file in python returns an iterator by default

Comment: It's not necessary, but it was an option that I found. So, if it is not necessary, i can remove it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

would work i think

```
import re
with open("info.dat") as f:
   for match in re.findall("\d+ 2[\s\n]*\d+ 1",f.read()):
       print match
```

see also : https://repl.it/repls/TatteredViciousResources

another alternative is

```
lines = f.readlines()
for line,nextline in zip(lines,lines[1:]):
    if line.strip().endswith("2") and nextline.strip().endswith("1"):
       print(line+nextline)
```

Comment: The last code won't work if `'1'` is in the last line of the file.

Comment: Thanks a lot. it's that I looking for. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop with `enumerate` with a `if` statement to condition the lines, and then if the condition is true, append the two lines into the list `final_lines`:

```
final_lines = []
with open('file.dat') as f:
    lines = f.readlines()
    for i,line in enumerate(lines):
        if line.split()[1] == '2' and lines[i+1].split()[1] == '1':
            final_lines.extend([line,lines[i+1]])
```

And now:

```
print(final_lines)
```

Would return your desired list.

Answer (score 0):

You are a beginner at Python which is great, so I am going to take a more elementary approach. It's a huge file so you are better reading a line at at time and keeping only that line, but you actually need two lines to identify the pattern so keep two. consider the following:

```
    fp = open('file.dat')
    last_line = fp.readline()
    next_line = fp.readline()
    while next_line:
        # logic to split the lines into a pair 
        # of numbers and check to see if the 
        # 2 and 1 end last_line and next_line
        # and outputting
        last_line = next_line
        next_line = fp.readline()
```

This follows good, readable software patterns, and requires a minimum of resources.